# Equality of probability of finite hitting time for irreducible states in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose I have a finite state Markov Chain with state space $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Suppose I further have that $\{1,2\}$,$\{3,4\}$ and $\{5,6\}$ are irreducible classes where $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are closed.

Suppose I want to calculate $P_5[T_{\{1,2\}}<\infty]$ and $P_6[T_{\{1,2\}}<\infty]$. Here $T_C$ is the first hitting time at $C\subset S$. Now, why can I not give the following argument:

> $5$ leads to $\{1,2\}$ in finite number of steps if and only if $6$ leads to $\{1,2\}$ in finite number of steps, because $6$ and $5$ communicate with each other. Hence $P_5[T_{\{1,2\}}<\infty]=P_6[T_{\{1,2\}}<\infty]$.

This argument is clearly not valid (an exercise in Hoel Port Stone shows I am wrong). But I can't find any flaw with it.

Also, when are these equal?

Suppose I had a different problem where the state space $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are irreducible and closed respectively, and we want to find $P_5[T_{1}<\infty]$ and $P_5[T_{2}<\infty]$. Are they equal, by my previous "argument"? Here by abuse of notation, consider $T_j=T_{\{j\}}$.

Answer (score 1):

To see a counterexample to your argument, let for example the transition probabilities:

1. $6 \to 5= 0.01$ and $6 \to \{3,4\}=0.99$,
2. $5 \to 6= 0.01$ and $5 \to \{1,2\}=0.99$.

Now, a simple calculation shows that $$P_6[T_{1,2}<+\infty]\le 0.01 < 0.99 \le P_5(T_{1,2}<+\infty)$$

For them to be equal, you need certain symmetry conditions on the transitions probabilities from states $5$ to $6$ as you can see from the above counterexample. So, actually equality would be a special case and not the rule. But in your second question, this is different. The probabilities $P_5[T_1<+\infty]$ and $P_5[T_2<+\infty]$ are indeed equal, since the following events are equivalent $$(T_2 \mid X_0=5)=+\infty \iff (T_1 \mid X_0=5)=+\infty$$ Namely, if starting from $5$ your chain visits $1$ then this implies that the chain will visit $2$ by the "closedness" of $\{1,2\}$. And conversely, if the chain visits $2$ this implies that the chain will certainly visit $1$.

Comment: Thanks. But where exactly does the logic not work in the first case?

Comment: Even if $6$ leads to $\{1,2\}$ in a finite number of steps, it doesnt necessarily mean $5$ leads to $\{1,2\}$ in a finite number of steps since $5$ can lead to $\{3,4\}$

Comment: Suppose $6$ leads to $(1,2)$ in finite number of steps. Then as $5$ communicates with $6$, $5$ leads to $6$ and hence to $(1,2)$ in finite number of steps. And conversely.

Comment: @LandonCarter Yes, this is correct (5 leads to (1,2) iff 6 leads to (1,2) this is true). But the probability of this happening is different.

Comment: This is what I'm not getting. I have two events $A$ and $B$ and I know that $A\iff B$. Then $P(A)=P(B)$. But this seems not to work here!!

Comment: @LandonCarter This is not even true. $5\to 6=0.1$ and $5\to {3,4}=0.9$ but $6\to 5=0.1$ and $6\to (1,2)=0.9$ gives a counterexample. In this case $5,6$ communicate. This is not a property of transitive states that communicate. Two things are possible but not equal probable.

Comment: I get the counterexamples, but I still do not get why this is happening, I'm sorry. Could you kindly explain your last sentence a bit?

Comment: Oh, ok. I get it now that you edited the comment. Thank you.

Comment: @LandonCarter Here it is: If $A \iff B$, then indeed $P(A)=P(B)$. Your sentence "6 leads to (1,2) in finite number of steps" is wrong. The correct sense is :"6 **could** lead to (1,2) in finite number of steps" and then as "5 communicates wtih 6, 5 **can** lead to (1,2) and conversely." This is a correct sentence. So, when calculating probabilities you want to measure how likely this **could** is. And there can be a big difference.

Comment: @LandonCarter  A path starting from $6$ can be much more/less likely to end up in $\{1,2\}$ than a path starting from $5$. That is measured here. Your argument only guarantees you, that you $can$, nothing more. It does say to you how likely this is. I hope this helps....

Comment: Actually, I realized that the two events are not defined on the same probability space. The probability measures are different i.e $P_5$ and $P_6$. So, even though the events are "English-wise" same, their probabilities can't be said to be same. But in the second example, the probability measure is also same i.e. $P_5$. Hence equality in probability follows.